# EE 5.1.3 Install Error

Tags: install, ee5

I'm trying to install EE 5.1.3 on my server but keep getting error:

```
Exception Caught

No such property: 'db' on EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Legacy\Facade

ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Legacy/Facade.php:120

Stack Trace: Please include when reporting this error

#0 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Legacy/Facade.php(30): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Legacy\Facade->get('db')
#1 ee/installer/controllers/wizard.php(853): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Legacy\Facade->__get('db')
#2 ee/installer/controllers/wizard.php(272): Wizard->do_install()
#3 [internal function]: Wizard->_remap('do_install', Array)
#4 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(241): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(110): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)
#6 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(151): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))
#7 admin.php(153): require_once('...')
#7 admin.php(153): require_once('...')
```

I have doubled checked that the DB is, in fact, up and running and connected to it using all same credentials in entered on the admin.php install wizard page.

Any help or direction in getting this resolved would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the paths and mysqli settings you used are correct?

Comment: I double checked the mysqli settings by connecting to the db from a third-party client. The install wizard doesn't ask for any paths like the old versions used to.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my host changed from using "localhost" for accessing the db and had to use a different host. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check `$config['database']` array in `config.php` file. If your localhost is running on a different port, you will have to add the port in the hostname in the `config.php` file like `localhost:9090`